# Redirect all HTTP traffic to localhost

Tags: redirect

Too much here and I've already spent hours trying to find my answer, to no avail.

I run a small ISP. We do not use any form of PPP. However, I control the clients' routers. The client router have their default gateways normally set to use my network gateway. However, if I change the client's default gateway to point to an alias of my server, whenever they try to go anywhere on the internet, even if it's *google.com*, I want them to go to *myserver/YouHaveNotPaidYourBill.php*.

I use Debian and Lighttpd on the server.

I have tried everything I can think of, and the server simply redirects the packets to the real gateway. This isn't what I want.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should be on ServerFault, however I thought I'd mention that this is a *super* shady thing for you to do. It's like you're running a MITM attack against your customers. Just cut them off and send a letter, don't break their internet in weird ways.

Comment: Indeed, this is awful practice.  I've many times seen this sort of thing on automated monitoring computers/devices, that didn't have any browser so there was no way to find out WHY communication with the server was failing.

Answer (score 0):

Your best chance is to poison your client's DNS, and have any DNS request point to your server.

Be warned, non-http traffic will fail silently, so clients that don't browse (ie: a line used for torrenting, for VoIP, or simply, someone who chats but doesn't browse) will only see internet failing silently and **will not** see the dialog.

Also, you'll fail to grab HTTPS traffic as well.  Since, for example, firefox uses HTTPS for google searches by default, average joe will try to access https://www.google.com, which you can't intercept to show your own message.  There no way; if there where, you'd be able to intercept any other https website (ie: banks) to show your own content.

Finally: this sort of thing is also interception of packages and/or MITM, and **may** be ilegal, depending on wherer you live.  It's not the same to drop communications (when he doesn't pay), and to intercept it like this.